# Rails [object] must exist ошибка

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, объекты

```
class Test < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :legal

  validates :legal, presence: true, allow_nil: true

  validates :ref, length: { minimum: 1 }, allow_nil: true
end

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :ref %>
  <%= f.collection_select :ref, Legal.all, :id, :name_s %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :ref1 %>
  <%= f.text_field :ref1 %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :value_s %>
  <%= f.text_field :value_s %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Казалось бы банально, ибо запрос сохранения выдается очевидный:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"*************", "test"=>{"ref"=>"1", "ref1"=>"1212", "value_s"=>"23232"}, "commit"=>"Create Test"}

Однако возникает ошибка

> Legal must exist

при том что в таблице legal явно есть запись с id = 1

Answer (score 1):

У вас в модели обязательное поле `legal`, однако в форме такого поля нет, и в параметрах его нет. Единственное упоминание `Legal` в выпадающем списке `f.collection_select`, однако поле называется `ref`. Когда вы заполняете и пытаетесь сохранить модель, срабатывает валидация

```
validates :legal, presence: true, allow_nil: true
```

Comment: значит мне необходимо добавить поле legal на форму? как это сделать?

Comment: @ilyasJuly А для чего это поле предназначено? Оно как-то связно с моделью Legal или у него другое назначение? Вообще да, нужно либо добавить для него выпадающий список, либо поместить его скрытое (hidden) поле, либо изменить валидацию этого поля в модели.

Comment: Да, в поле ref должен сохраняться id из таблицы legal

Comment: @ilyasJuly У вас в модели есть поле legal_id (сужу по связи belongs_to :legal)? Если есть, оно какое значение должно принимать?

Comment: Маленькое уточнение. `legal` - отношение, а не поле. Кстати, в 5 рельсах для `belongs_to` по дефолту `required: true`, так что отдельная валидация не нужна.

Comment: мне необходимо победить ошибку. как сделать так чтобы код работал?  данные сохранялись?

Comment: @ilyasJuly уберите валидацию validates :legal, presence: true, allow_nil: true, посмотрите, после этого сохранение идет?

Comment: ничего не изменилось

Comment: @ilyasJuly, почему id должен сохраниться в `ref`? По дефолту, `ActiveRecord` будет использовать `legal_id` для сохранения внешнего ключа. Соотвественно, и в `collection_select` первым аргументом должен быть `legal_id`. Либо в модели надо определеить отношение так: `belongs_to :legal, foreign_key: :ref`. Одно из двух)

Comment: спасибо большое!  Использовал belongs_to :legal, foreign_key: :ref

Comment: @ilyasJuly, только если в модели `Legal` указано "зеркальное" отношение, то и в нём надо указать что `foreign_key` другой.